# Calcular distancia entre dos puntos, teorema de Pitágoras (distancia euclidiana)

Tags: python

Para conocer la distancia entre dos puntos simplemente debemos aplicar el Teorema de Pitagoras (distancia euclidiana).

Yo con Python lo haría así:

```
import math
x = [x[0], x[1]]
y = [y[0], y[1]]
P = math.sqrt((x1-x0)**2 + (y1-y0)**2)
print (P)
```

Pero veo que también se puede hacer con NumPy por ejemplo y seguro muchas más opciones. ¿Que me puede motivar para hacerlo de una manera u otra?

Comment: Hola buenas he encontrado un sitio donde debaten sobre tu problema con diferentes soluciones aquí te lo dejo: https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/264739

Comment: Hola @InfoTipsconJavitoBCN lo he leido, el original es [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy) pero no termino de aclararme. Realmente ahora estoy empezando a leer sobre NumPy y voy perdido.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy es una libreria para tratamiento de numeros en forma de arrays. Para quienes han usado matlab, se pueden sentir cómodos con numpy, aunque su definicion de dimensiones es diferente.

Uno de los casos donde usar numpy tiene ventajas es las operaciones de vectores y matrices, por ejemplo. Tambien es útil por las facilidades para indexar y acceder a los elementos.

Ejemplos:

```
import numpy as np

[1,2,3,4] + 5 # Esto genera una excepcion por que se está sumando una lista y un entero
np.array([1,2,3,4]) + 5 # resultado: array([6, 7, 8, 9])

m = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
mp = np.array(m)

m[2,2] # Excepción
mp[2,2] # resultado: 11
mp[1:,2:] # resultado: array([[ 7,  8],  [11, 12]])

m*m # Excepción
# multiplicación elemento por elemento
mp*mp # resultado: array([[  1,   4,   9,  16],
                          [ 25,  36,  49,  64],
                          [ 81, 100, 121, 144]])
# producto punto (uso de transpuesta)
np.dot(mp,mp.T) # resultado: array([[ 30,  70, 110],
                                    [ 70, 174, 278],
                                    [110, 278, 446]])
```

En el caso de la distancia entre 2 puntos supongamos que se tiene un listado de puntos xy y se quiere calcular la distancia de todos estos a un punto P:

```
x = np.arange(1,10)
y = np.arange(1,10)
xy = np.array([x,y]).T
p = np.array([5,5])
print(xy)
>>> array([[1, 1],
   [2, 2],
   [3, 3],
   [4, 4],
   [5, 5],
   [6, 6],
   [7, 7],
   [8, 8],
   [9, 9]])
```

Y definiendo d como la lista de distancias:

```
d = np.sqrt(np.sum((xy-p)**2, axis=1))
>>> print(d)
[5.65685425 4.24264069 2.82842712 1.41421356 0.         1.41421356
 2.82842712 4.24264069 5.65685425]
```